# Morris graphs. Have custom yValues

Tags: morris.js

In Line Graphs, is possible to set the ymin and ymax values and automatically generate the ranges divided equally.

But I would like to set my own ranges.

example ():

0-5
5-15
15-100
100-10000

Is this posible?